# Forked repository to project

Tags: git, composer-php, github-api

This is my first experience of creating a fork repository, updated few things in the repository now I want to download this as package using composer to my project in order to see the broken things to fix.

I want to download using composer something similar to this

```
{
    "require": {
        "fadion/bouncy": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/vikram0460/Bouncy

Comment: git clone https://github.com/vikram0460/Bouncy.git

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@github.com:vikram0460/Bouncy.git"
    }
]
```

Comment: it is not downloaded the packge